# ¿Cómo soluciono este error .push is not a function?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Intento guardar el `ID` como variable para luego insertarlo en un `array` pero me muestra :

> ESEAadn.push is not a function.

**PHP**

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $cartaNombre = $row["Carta"];

   // echo "<input type='image' src='$cartaNombre' value='$cartaNombre' alt='no se encuentra' width='7%' class='cartas' name='carta' onclick='this.disabled = true; valor(value)'>";
    echo "<img  src='$cartaNombre' alt='no se encuentra' width='7%' class='cartas' name='carta' id='$cartaNombre ' onclick='this.disabled = true; valor(this.id)'>";

}
```

**JS**

```
 var ESEAadn = [];
 function valor(carta_id) {
   var value = carta_id;
   ESEAadn.push(value);
 }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás inicializando tu variable `ESEAadn`?

Comment: ¿De que tipo es `ESEAadn`?

Comment: debes agregar var ESEAadn = []

Comment: Creo que podriamos coincidir en que no esta declarado ESEAadn y como no esta declarado no puedes meter tu variable en un arreglo que no existe o que aún no esta definido.

Comment: disculpen no lo puse pero si estas declarada como array vacio y global fuera de la function

Comment: Puede que no lo este tomando cuando entra a la función deberias de meterlo dentro de la función.

Comment: Como menciona @A. Cedano , el código en teoría debería funcionar correctamente. el error puede que esté en otra parte del código.

Answer (score 0):

Debe ser otro error, ya que la *función*... ¡funciona!

Por lo demás, esto:

```
var value = carta_id;
```

no es necesario, ya que el valor lo recibes como parámetro en la función.

```js
var ESEAadn = [];

function valor(carta_id) {
  // no necesario
  // var value = carta_id;
  ESEAadn.push(carta_id);
  alert(ESEAadn);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h2>Funciona</h2>
  <p>Prueba: se insertará el valor 1 en el array cada vez que pulses en el botón. Y cada vez verás un mensaje de alerta con el contenido del array de JS</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="valor(1);">Agrega y mira la pantalla!</button>
</body>

</html>
```